# event after changing input type=date on android browser (jquery)

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, date

I want to add an event after the date is set on mobile browsers.

so far, I have the following code:
Html:

```
   <input type="date" value=""/>
```

jquery:

```
var event = isiOS()?'blur':'change';
$('[type="date"]').on(event, function(){
    //do something!
})

function isiOS(){
    var i = 0,
    iDevice = ['iPad', 'iPhone', 'iPod'];
    for ( ; i < iDevice.length ; i++ ) {
        if( navigator.platform === iDevice[i] ){
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

it works on iOS and Android Firefox / Chrome 
- but, on Default Android browser (Android 4.4) it does not do anything.

I tried all events I could find:
"blur" and "focusout" are fired before the date window is opened.
"focusin" and "focus" are fired many times when the date window is opening, and after pressing "ok" (around 3time when opening, 5/6times when closing)

So I am stock here..

You guys have any idea which event could be use on Android default browser?

thanks

Comment: I managed a fall-back: if the browser is the android default one, then I use jquery datepicker.

Comment: forgot to say "hi" again: hi guys!